# Unusual PowerShell returning value

Tags: powershell

I have this part of script, which calls a function in a external file script:

```
    #CheckIn della changelist
    $tmpresult = CheckIn-ChangeList -LogPath $LogFullPathName -number $ChangeListNumber -FilesToRevert $ChangeListFiles
    if ($tmpresult -eq 0)
    {
        $result = $True
    }
    else
    {
        $result = $False
    }
```

The function is the followning:

```
Function CheckIn-ChangeList
{

[CmdletBinding()]

Param ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$LogPath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string[]]$FilesToRevert,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$number)

Process
{
    try 
    {
        Log-Write -LogPath $LogPath -LogText "Inizio CheckIn" -NewLine $True
        #Questo comando esegue il checkIn
        p4 submit -c $number
        Log-Write -LogPath $LogPath -LogText ("CheckIn per changelist n° " + $($number).ToString() + " eseguito correttamente") -NewLine $True
        return 0
    }
    catch
    {
        Manage-Exception -LogPath $LogPath -number $number -ErrMessage $_.Exception -FilesToRevert $FilesToRevert
        return 1
    }
}
}
```

I expect that the return value would be 0 or 1 which can be naturally casted to `$True` or `$False`, but this is the console output:

```
edit //depot/***.map#130
edit //depot/***.cs#139
edit //depot/*.xml#149
Change 285339 submitted.
0
[DBG]: PS C:\Users\mmarcianesi>> $tmpresult.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                        
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                        
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

is this normal? I have no experience with power shell programming.

Comment: If you're using a `Process` block to set up a pipeline, yes, that's normal. Since you aren't processing pipeline items, however, it's not logical to use it. Remove that block and just put the statements in the cmdlet directly under the `Param` block and the return value should be what you expect.

Comment: That would be the `Process { }` block in `CheckIn-ChangeList` I'm talking about. If you're free to change that, remove that block, it's not necessary or required in this case. If it's just poorly written but you're not free to change it, you'll have to process the output instead by just picking the first element in the pipeline (`$tmpresult[0]`).

Comment: If you post as answer I'll accept.

Comment: I doubt that is going to solve your problem. I suspect the additional output is from this statement: `p4 submit -c $number` - change it to `p4 submit -c $number |Out-Null` or `p4 submit -c $number |% { Write-Host $_ }` to avoid it cluttering the function output